# retrieving the attribute value from the request.getSession

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, request

Correct me if i am doing wrong.

I am using the below code to display in the jsp page. Can use the below code snippet to display companyName value.?

```
        <% String compName = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("companyName"); %>

//    inside the form     
    <input type="hidden" name="companyName" value="<c:out value="${compName}" />" />
            <script>
                $('#myLink').on('click', function() { $('#apForm').submit(); });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To your question:the answer is **NO**!

The reason is that scope of `compName` is `page`,but if you access it via `${compName}`,you must set the value first

To access `compName`,there are two ways:

A. using java code to get it

```
<input type="hidden" name="companyName" value="<%=compName%>" />
```

B. first set the attribute value via `request`,then get it as you done

```
<% 
  String compName = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("companyName");
  request.setAttribute("compName",compName);
 %>
<input type="hidden" name="companyName" value="<c:out value="${compName}" />" />
```

Comment: i want to send the value of 'compName' in the hidden paramter. HOw can i do that?

Comment: your scriptlet code is redundant. OP can just use ${compName} if the session attribute has already been set.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte because the session variable is caled `companyName` not `compName`